# Using Javascript to Open a New Page and Populate Form Values There

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, settimeout, form-fields

I am using JavaScript in a bookmarklet to populate form elements on a website:

```
javascript:var f = document.forms[0];
f.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = 'myname';
f.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value = 'mypassword';
f.getElementsByTagName('input')[2].click
```

This works. However what I would like to create is a bookmarklet so that it opens the target page, and populates the values there; however it seems that onces the page is loaded, other JavaScript codes are not executed. So, the following doesn't work.

```
javascript:window.location("mywebsite");var f = document.forms[0];
f.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = 'myname';
f.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value = 'mypassword';
f.getElementsByTagName('input')[2].click;
```

I have also experimented with setTimeout to delay the execution of my code, but that didn't work.

```
javascript:var f = document.forms[0];setTimeout("f.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = 'myname';f.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value = 'mypassword';f.getElementsByTagName('input')[2].click;",1000);
```

How can I load my script once I know the target page is fully loaded?

Comment: By the way, I am dealing with this because for some reason, the webpage doesn't trigger Chrome to remember the website. The target website is here: https://newmail.bilkent.edu.tr/src/login.php

Comment: Just to point out: your passwort will be visible to everybody that has access to the javascript code!

Comment: Yes, I know. I am just trying to create a bookmark for my own use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Greasemonkey](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/24790/beginner-guide-for-greasemonkey-scripts-in-google-chrome/) is built into Chrome, sounds like you are trying to reinvent the wheel. Install a JS file and it will run when the page loads.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes the answer actually is obvious.

Answer (score 8):

I don't use GreaseMonkey as a personal rule, to code for browsers that shouldn't use it. Bookmarklets are a least-common-denominator approach to automate logins when your system is locked down and won't allow install of Greasemonkey, Roboform, etc.

I've coded a lot of login bookmarklets and thought about what you're trying to do: add some script that gets executed after a page loads. I came to this page looking for the solution, but now I'm glad it doesn't work.

Think about the security implications of this. If it were possible to echo keystrokes to to a loaded page, it would also be able to listen to keystrokes and send them elsewhere -- very bad.

If you want to automate logins, try a bookmarklet pattern like this (remove line breaks):

```
javascript:
    u='my_username';
    p='my_password';
    l='https://my_server/signon.aspx'; 
    if(location!=l)location=l;
    else{
     g=document.getElementById; 
     ue=(g('username') || g('userid') || g('login_name'));
     if(ue){
      ue.value=u;
      pe=(g('password') || g('pw') || g('pin'));
      pe.value = p;
      b=(g('submit_button') || g('signon_button') || g('login_button'));
      document.close();
      if(b)b.click();
     } 
    }
```

Clicking the link once takes you to the signon.aspx page.  Once the username field is available on the loaded page, clicking the same link again will fill the form and submit.

So it's one more click than you hoped, but if you put the bookmarklet on a toolbar it's hardly any delay. Good luck!

Comment: Actually, this was what I ended up using, but I had two toolbar buttons next to each other, one for the link, the other for the script. Your approach is clever.